# iPhone X (unlike my old iPhone 6s+) photos not synced to Win7

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

I use iCloud software for Windows 7 (with the latest update).

**GOOD**: My old iPhone 6s+ photos are all downloaded to iCloud PC app.

**PROBLEM**: New iPhoneX (iOS 12.0.1) pics do not sync (few thousand of them). If I try to redownload pics from 2018, it only downloads 6s+ photos again and then it stops.

HELPFUL INFO:
1. **ALL** my pics are visible on iCloud on the web.

2. In Windows iCloud app:

   - My Photo Stream is not selected
   - iCloud Photo Libarary, Download new Photos and Keep High efficiency original are selected.
3. On iPhone X:
   iCloud Photos is clicked, Optimise iPhone Storage is selected, Download and keep originals is not and Upload to my Photo Stream is not. Shared Albums is on (though I don't use it).

(I no longer use the old iPhone, but preserved the same iCloud account)